# symbolizing that sentence

Tags: logic

Try to give a simple English rendering of the following open formulae of PredL, given the following interpretation:

- D = the set of all people (living or dead)
- $M_{xy}$:  x is y’s biological mother
- $F_{xy}$:  x is y’s biological father.

a) $\exists w \exists z (M_{zx} . M_{zy} \& F_{wx} . F_{wy})$

b) $\exists z ((M_{xz} V F_{xz}) \& (M_{zy} V F_{zy}))$

Thanks for help.

Comment: WHat do the dots $.$ and $V$ mean?

Comment: dot  is and (conjunction )  V (disjunction).

Comment: I assumed & was for conjunction, is that the case or not?

Comment: true That is also conjuction

Answer (score -2, accepted):

So $a)$ says there is a $w$ such that $w$ is the father of $x$ and also the father of $y$ and there is a $z$ such that $z$ is the mother of $x$ and also the mother of $y$. So in fact it says that $x$ and $y$ (the free variables) are *siblings*.

$(b)$ says that there is a $z$ such that $x$ is the mother of $z$ or the father of $z$ (so $z$ is a child of $x$) and for that same $z$ we have that $y$ is a child of $z$. In total, both must hold and so it says that $y$ is a grandchild of $x$ (with intermediate parent $z$).

Comment: Thank you so much !!! it is really helpful!